# VSCode checking invalid references in Angular template

Tags: html, angular, validation, visual-studio-code

VSCode doesn't warn/underline the invalid/not existing references in the html template like this below

```
  <div class="header" color="primary" (click)="doSomething9999()"> <!-- click handler doesnt exist -->
```

I have tslint, eslint plugin installed, but they don't warn me about this kind of issue.

Which settings can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Csaba

(I searched in the Google but somehow I could not focus on an exact solution)

Answer (score 1):

so I tried some plugin and the
'Angular Language Service' - Editor services for Angular templates
could help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

didn't you forget to add a slash in closing tag - `</div>`.

Comment: div is closed well